# DHTMLX Gantt Chart Pagination

Tags: dhtmlx

I have to implement Gantt chart pagination in my project. Explore a lot but couldn't find the solution to achieve. I am reading JSON data to populating Gantt chart and need to achieve pagination.Need quick help.

Answer (score 0):

We have no built-in solution for solving this problem now. 
How the pagination should works? 
You could try to declare a filter or range from start_date to end_date and add required buttons to pages. Then set changing displayed range by pressing the button.

Comment: Hi,

I have the same issue. I have a huge amount of data and when loading it on gantt chart, it takes a lot of time.

Is there a way to dynamically load the load the data( like, using page_start and page_end parameters for example ), when user scrolls?

Comment: Hello, There is no built-in pagination feature, but there are other things that might help you.
If you have a lot of tasks you can use smart rendering extension. In the following example gantt loads 30000 tasks within a few seconds: https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/02_extensions/13_smart_rendering.html
Also, if your projects have many tasks, there is an option that controls tasks tree, you can set it to false then load tasks:
gantt.config.open_tree_initially = false;
Please read an article Ways to Increase Performance https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__performance.html